# Pulsating image rings css animations

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to create a 'pulsating rings' animation around a circle image using css animations.

My image is a circle and 400px wide. I have managed to get the whole image to pulse, however I'm not quite sure how to create and animate the sepatate pulsating rings around the image.

I would like to image to be static, and the rings pulsate around it.

My code so far;

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <img class="pulse" src="http://freevector.co/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/51770-placeholder-in-a-circle-outline.png"></div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  padding: 20px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse_animation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.pulse {
  -webkit-animation-name: 'pulse_animation';
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3000ms;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 70% 70%;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation: pulsate 3s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

I have created a [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/johnny_s/gpm5x3kp/1/).

I would like to create rings similar to the [example here](http://codepen.io/danest/pen/GxfqB/).

I'm sure I am very close. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You are breathing location. You can copy the same code right?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand :/

Comment: Man, I was appreciating the work you did. Why not use the same code from codepen in your fiddle?

Comment: OKay, you have a fundamental mistake. The image is single, along with the circle. You **cannot** animate the circle alone.

Comment: OKay, I can help you with it. Just to confirm. You need both pulsating as well as breathing?

Comment: You could do this using just one image and one container element like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/77f7mu0x/). Or better still with just one element if you use the image as background image.

Comment: Here is another style -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/gpm5x3kp/4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need a new div with the same width/height of image, add a border to it and animate.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <img class="pulse" src="http://freevector.co/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/51770-placeholder-in-a-circle-outline.png">
  <div class="pulse-ring">
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pulse-ring {
  content: '';
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 10px solid #F00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: 18px;
  animation: pulsate infinite 1s;
}
```

[Example in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ianramosc/1ys2uxrc/)

Comment: Can I just ask - what is the purpose of the `top: 18px and left: 18px` - how is this calculated? In my live html page my setup is slightly different and I notice that my pulsating circle is not in line (it's top left of the page as opposed to on the circle).

Comment: Oh, sure. In JSFiddle I have no parent with `position: relative` so it'll be relative to my body, and body has a little margin for default.

Comment: If you set `position: relative` for `.container`, you can calculate this way:
`.container` has 20px of padding for each side, then I have 20px between image and `.container`. `.pulse-ring` border is set to 10px and needs to be outside image border. 

Top = Outer padding - pulse-ring border.

[Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/ianramosc/1ys2uxrc/2/)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://freevector.co/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/51770-placeholder-in-a-circle-outline.png" />
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>

.circle {
  border: solid 13px black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
  animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g2taoods/)

Basically add another div, give it the circle shape, overlay it on the image, the add the animation to it :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did this.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ombmrp

Basically I have a circle shape, then I draw bigger rings around it like 4 time. Then only used scale/opacity animation to make it look so much better with some delay on each ring.

Hope this helps!

Code:

```
@keyframes pulsate {
   0% {
      transform: scale(1, 1);
      opacity: 0;
   }
   50% {
      opacity: 1;
   }
   100% {
      transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
      opacity: 0;
   }
}

.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

span {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

.red-medium-circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  border: 2px solid red;
  animation: pulsate infinite ease-in-out 2s 0.3s;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```